# Matching Pairs Problem in excel using basic functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

May I know how to check whether the Current Pairs match with the Ideal Pairs by using excel functions?

For example: The Current Pair of 1&8 does not match with the Ideal Pair of 1&14 and 1&29

I would also like to count the total number of matching pairs at the end. I have tried out different methods by using countifs() or match(), but in vain.

Appreciate your answer!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below formula to count all matching pairs.

```
=SUM(--(IFERROR(XMATCH(B2:B7&C2:C7,F2:F7&G2:G7,0),0)>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I wonder whether there would be a simpler method without the use of "XMATCH" and "SUM(--)"?

Can match() and sum() be the alternative in this case?

Comment: In your case, the result should be 1 as there is only 1 matching pair those two ranges?

Comment: Two matching pairs `2,3` and `4,5`.

Comment: If it older version of excel then you can use `=SUM(--(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B3&C2:C3,E2:E3&F2:F3,0),0)>0))` as an array formula enter by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a column at the right that will show 0 for not matching and 1 for matching so that it is easier for summing them together to get the final result and to prevent the long formula used at one time? 

So the result of the column would be like "000101". and summing up would get 2 as the final answer

Comment: Do you mind explaining what sum(--) means? what are the functions of the two dashes and is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Then use match formula only. `MATCH(B2:B3&C2:C3,E2:E3&F2:F3,0),0)`. Remember, you must enter formula as array entry for non 365 versions of excel.

Comment: Basically `--` push to convert boolean logic to numeric values. And then `Sum()` to count total matching pairs quantity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is your formula only work for columns that are the same length? The formula does not seem to be working in my case.